# Lambda Script Update to Change Instance Size

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I would like to update this script to stop this instance, make a backup, change the size and then restart the instance.

Basically I'm trying to mesh together three scripts.    All say they are written in Python 2.7 but the syntax doesn't match up.

See the scripts below.   Can I really just mash up these scripts?   The first script looks like I would do something like this:

```
     def lambda_handler(event, context):
     ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
     ec2.change_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
     print 'started your instances: ' + str(instances)
```

But I'm not even sure if that's the right syntax.   Where in the second script says:

```
    client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=my_instance, 
    Attribute='instanceType', Value='m3.xlarge')
```

Obviously I would change the variable, but not sure if I need the def lamba_handler syntax.

Can you anyone point me in the right direction?

Script 1

```
    import boto3
    region = 'us-east-1'
    instances = ['XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX']

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
        ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
        print 'started your instances: ' + str(instances)

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
        ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
        print 'started your instances: ' + str(instances)
```

Script 2

```
    client = boto3.client('ec2')

    # Insert your Instance ID here
    region = 'us-east-1'
    instances = ['XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX']

    # Stop the instance
    client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instances])
    waiter=client.get_waiter('instance_stopped')
    waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[my_instance])

    # Change the instance type
    client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=my_instance, 
    Attribute='instanceType', Value='m3.xlarge')

    # Start the instance
    client.start_instances(InstanceIds=[my_instance])
```

Comment: Script 2 looks perfectly good (except for the mixed used of `instances` and `my_instance`. Is your problem that you don't know how to use it as a Lambda function? How will the Lambda function know which instance to change? (That is, how is that ID passed to the function?)

Answer (score 0):

import boto3
    region = 'us-east-1'
    instances = ['XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX']

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print 'started your instances: ' + str(instances)
    waiter=ec2.get_waiter('instance_stopped')
    waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[my_instance])

# Change the instance type
    ec2.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=my_instance, 
Attribute='instanceType', Value='m3.xlarge')

    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print 'started your instances: ' + str(instances)
```